Image Field type disappeared
Cannot add a new field of type "Image Field" to a content type definition, because it is missing from the Field type drop down list (Boolean Field, Content Picker Field, Date Time Field, ...).
How could it disappeared?
In the production environment (prod) it is still there.
The prod has the same binary, only the DB differs merely because of the content. (In principal)
The development environment (dev) starts without images (only static images shows).
If I restore the DB from prod to dev, Orchard doesn't even start, it throws this exception:
Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeAttributeStrategy.ShapeAttributeBindingStrategy.PerformInvoke(DisplayContext displayContext, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object serviceInstance) in
\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAttributeStrategy\ShapeAttributeBindingStrategy.cs:73
Orchard version: Orchard v.1.10.1.0

Since the DB was the same in the two environment and the binary in the production was built from the code on dev environment, the difference had to be in the Orchard files.
Replacing the Modules directory content from an old backup solved the problem.
